# Strange phantom table in the MySQL Percona 8.0

Tags: percona, tokudb

I have MySQL server: mysql  Ver 8.0.21-12 for Linux on x86_64 (Percona Server (GPL), Release 12, Revision 7ddfdfe).

Used to have several TokuDB tables. Changed them to InnoDB, disabled the TOKU plugin.
Trying to migrate to a new instance without TokuDB - I get this error

```
Table 'plp.#sql-e70b_1135191d' requires the 'TokuDB' storage engine, which was removed in Percona Server 8.0.28
```

I don't have any tables with that name. But I have found a file `@0023sql@002de70b_113519_557.sdi` in my data/db dir. Deleting the obviously doesn't help.

I tried to restart the server, the table is still there.

What is this? And how I can delete the table.

```
  "mysqld_version_id": 80021,
  "dd_version": 80021,
  "sdi_version": 80019,
  "dd_object_type": "Table",
  "dd_object": {
    "name": "#sql-e70b_1135191d",
    "mysql_version_id": 80021,
    "created": 20221124150830,
    "last_altered": 20221124150830,
    "hidden": 4,
    "options": "avg_row_length=0;explicit_encryption=0;key_block_size=0;keys_disabled=0;pack_record=1;stats_auto_recalc=0;stats_sample_pages=0;",
    "columns": [
      {
        "name": "id",
        "type": 4,
        "is_nullable": false,
        "is_zerofill": false,
        "is_unsigned": true,
        "is_auto_increment": true,
        "is_virtual": false,
        "hidden": 1,
        "ordinal_position": 1,
        "char_length": 10,
        "numeric_precision": 10,
        "numeric_scale": 0,
        "numeric_scale_null": false,
        "datetime_precision": 0,
        "datetime_precision_null": 1,
        "has_no_default": false,
        "default_value_null": false,
        "srs_id_null": true,
        "srs_id": 0,
        "default_value": "AAAAAA==",
        "default_value_utf8_null": true,
        "default_value_utf8": "",
        "default_option": "",
        "update_option": "",
        "comment": "",
        "generation_expression": "",
        "generation_expression_utf8": "",
        "options": "interval_count=0;",
        "se_private_data": "",
        "engine_attribute": "",
        "secondary_engine_attribute": "",
        "column_key": 2,
        "column_type_utf8": "int unsigned",
        "elements": [],
        "collation_id": 8,
        "is_explicit_collation": false
      },
      {
        "name": "task_id",
        "type": 4,
        "is_nullable": true,
        "is_zerofill": false,
        "is_unsigned": true,
        "is_auto_increment": false,
        "is_virtual": false,
        "hidden": 1,
        "ordinal_position": 2,
        "char_length": 10,
        "numeric_precision": 10,
        "numeric_scale": 0,
        "numeric_scale_null": false,
        "datetime_precision": 0,
        "datetime_precision_null": 1,
        "has_no_default": false,
        "default_value_null": true,
        "srs_id_null": true,
        "srs_id": 0,
        "default_value": "",
        "default_value_utf8_null": true,
        "default_value_utf8": "",
        "default_option": "",
        "update_option": "",
        "comment": "",
        "generation_expression": "",
        "generation_expression_utf8": "",
        "options": "interval_count=0;",
        "se_private_data": "",
        "engine_attribute": "",
        "secondary_engine_attribute": "",
        "column_key": 4,
        "column_type_utf8": "int unsigned",
        "elements": [],
        "collation_id": 8,
        "is_explicit_collation": false
      },
      {
        "name": "account_id",
        "type": 4,
        "is_nullable": false,
        "is_zerofill": false,
        "is_unsigned": false,
        "is_auto_increment": false,
        "is_virtual": false,
        "hidden": 1,
        "ordinal_position": 3,
        "char_length": 11,
        "numeric_precision": 10,
        "numeric_scale": 0,
        "numeric_scale_null": false,
        "datetime_precision": 0,
        "datetime_precision_null": 1,
        "has_no_default": true,
        "default_value_null": false,
        "srs_id_null": true,
        "srs_id": 0,
        "default_value": "AAAAAA==",
        "default_value_utf8_null": true,
        "default_value_utf8": "",
        "default_option": "",
        "update_option": "",
        "comment": "",
        "generation_expression": "",
        "generation_expression_utf8": "",
        "options": "interval_count=0;",
        "se_private_data": "",
        "engine_attribute": "",
        "secondary_engine_attribute": "",
        "column_key": 4,
        "column_type_utf8": "int",
        "elements": [],
        "collation_id": 8,
        "is_explicit_collation": false
      },
      {
        "name": "debug",
        "type": 27,
        "is_nullable": false,
        "is_zerofill": false,
        "is_unsigned": false,
        "is_auto_increment": false,
        "is_virtual": false,
        "hidden": 1,
        "ordinal_position": 4,
        "char_length": 65535,
        "numeric_precision": 0,
        "numeric_scale": 0,
        "numeric_scale_null": true,
        "datetime_precision": 0,
        "datetime_precision_null": 1,
        "has_no_default": true,
        "default_value_null": false,
        "srs_id_null": true,
        "srs_id": 0,
        "default_value": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAA==",
        "default_value_utf8_null": true,
        "default_value_utf8": "",
        "default_option": "",
        "update_option": "",
        "comment": "",
        "generation_expression": "",
        "generation_expression_utf8": "",
        "options": "interval_count=0;",
        "se_private_data": "",
        "engine_attribute": "",
        "secondary_engine_attribute": "",
        "column_key": 1,
        "column_type_utf8": "text",
        "elements": [],
        "collation_id": 8,
        "is_explicit_collation": false
      },
      {
        "name": "date_create",
        "type": 19,
        "is_nullable": false,
        "is_zerofill": false,
        "is_unsigned": false,
        "is_auto_increment": false,
        "is_virtual": false,
        "hidden": 1,
        "ordinal_position": 5,
        "char_length": 19,
        "numeric_precision": 0,
        "numeric_scale": 0,
        "numeric_scale_null": true,
        "datetime_precision": 0,
        "datetime_precision_null": 0,
        "has_no_default": true,
        "default_value_null": false,
        "srs_id_null": true,
        "srs_id": 0,
        "default_value": "gAAAAAA=",
        "default_value_utf8_null": true,
        "default_value_utf8": "",
        "default_option": "",
        "update_option": "",
        "comment": "",
        "generation_expression": "",
        "generation_expression_utf8": "",
        "options": "interval_count=0;",
        "se_private_data": "",
        "engine_attribute": "",
        "secondary_engine_attribute": "",
        "column_key": 1,
        "column_type_utf8": "datetime",
        "elements": [],
        "collation_id": 8,
        "is_explicit_collation": false
      }
    ],
    "schema_ref": "plp",
    "se_private_id": 18446744073709552000,
    "engine": "TokuDB",
    "last_checked_for_upgrade_version_id": 0,
    "comment": "",
    "se_private_data": "",
    "engine_attribute": "",
    "secondary_engine_attribute": "",
    "row_format": 2,
    "partition_type": 0,
    "partition_expression": "",
    "partition_expression_utf8": "",
    "default_partitioning": 0,
    "subpartition_type": 0,
    "subpartition_expression": "",
    "subpartition_expression_utf8": "",
    "default_subpartitioning": 0,
    "indexes": [
      {
        "name": "PRIMARY",
        "hidden": false,
        "is_generated": false,
        "ordinal_position": 1,
        "comment": "",
        "options": "flags=0;",
        "se_private_data": "",
        "type": 1,
        "algorithm": 1,
        "is_algorithm_explicit": false,
        "is_visible": true,
        "engine": "TokuDB",
        "engine_attribute": "",
        "secondary_engine_attribute": "",
        "elements": [
          {
            "ordinal_position": 1,
            "length": 4,
            "order": 2,
            "hidden": false,
            "column_opx": 0
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "task_id",
        "hidden": false,
        "is_generated": false,
        "ordinal_position": 2,
        "comment": "",
        "options": "flags=0;",
        "se_private_data": "",
        "type": 3,
        "algorithm": 1,
        "is_algorithm_explicit": false,
        "is_visible": true,
        "engine": "TokuDB",
        "engine_attribute": "",
        "secondary_engine_attribute": "",
        "elements": [
          {
            "ordinal_position": 1,
            "length": 4,
            "order": 2,
            "hidden": false,
            "column_opx": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "account_id",
        "hidden": false,
        "is_generated": false,
        "ordinal_position": 3,
        "comment": "",
        "options": "flags=0;",
        "se_private_data": "",
        "type": 3,
        "algorithm": 1,
        "is_algorithm_explicit": false,
        "is_visible": true,
        "engine": "TokuDB",
        "engine_attribute": "",
        "secondary_engine_attribute": "",
        "elements": [
          {
            "ordinal_position": 1,
            "length": 4,
            "order": 2,
            "hidden": false,
            "column_opx": 2
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "foreign_keys": [],
    "check_constraints": [],
    "partitions": [],
    "collation_id": 8
  }
}
```

I don't want to run through the mysqldump, because DB is big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it.

```
> CHECK TABLE `#sql-e70b_1135191d`;

Can't find file: '#sql-e70b_1135191d' (errno: 2 - No such file or directory)

> DROP TABLE `#sql-e70b_1135191d`;

Storage engine can't drop table 'plp.#sql-e70b_1135191d' because it is missing. Use DROP TABLE IF EXISTS to remove it from data-dictionary.


> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `#sql-e70b_1135191d`;
```

And the table was deleted.